# how to: PRODUCT_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS

Tags: android

I heard that PRODUCT_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS can be used to add strings to native Android applications without having to actually edit the strings.xml of that application.

I tried following the steps in [this site](http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/build_new_device.html) (I created /vendor/.., etc), but there were build errors when I tried to use the strings in my activities.

How do I call in my activity a string (ex: R.string.x) which is declared in the overlay?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I've found this site, http://mmmyddd.github.io/wiki/android/overlay.html

It talks about Android Overlay Mechanism.

There are two types of overlay directories that affect a product:

- `PRODUCT_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS`: used by a particular product
- `DEVICE_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS`: used by several products that share a common device model

The `PRODUCT_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS` will override the `DEVICE_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS` if they contain same resources.

With Android SDK tool *aapt*, you will see this:

> -S  directory in which to find resources.  Multiple directories will be scanned
>         and the first match found (left to right) will take precedence.

As to how to add extra resources, we could achieve by add option *auto-add-overlay* from *aapt*

> --auto-add-overlay
>         Automatically add resources that are only in overlays.